# Alamofire Extra argument 'method' in call - with custom ParameterEncoding

Tags: swift, customization, alamofire

I'm trying to upload an array of objects in jsonSerialization and gzip. I wrote a struct as described in github.

```
struct JSONDocumentArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
private let array: [Document]
init(array:[Document]) {
    self.array = array
}
func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
    var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest

    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])

    if urlRequest!.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
        urlRequest!.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    }

    urlRequest!.httpBody = data

    return urlRequest!
}
```

}

Then in the request

```
request = customAlamofireManager.request(
        ServerURL ,
        method: .post,
        parameters: [objects],
        encoding: JSONDocumentArrayEncoding,
        headers: headers
    )
```

error is "extra argument method in call". This issue was discussed in github1508 [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508) But I cannot see a solution. Since the parameter is defined as [string:object], cannot pass in an array. Therefore even with customized struct for encoding, there's no way to pass in this body data. I'm thinking a work around maybe add a dummy key to the array and modify server api to catch the value of the dictionary. But there's no ideal.

Comment: Just tried to add a random key to array to make it a dictionary such as ["data": [obj]], still same error. Because the struct is expecting an array, not a dictionary. So it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question: Find a work around without using the default request method:

```
    func uploadBatchDocumentsWithDocs(_ documents: [Any]) {
        let headers = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.headers
         var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: (ServerURL + Api))!)
         urlRequest.httpMethod = "post"
         urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
         let jsonArrayencoding = JSONDocumentArrayEncoding(array: documents)           
         let jsonAryEncodedRequest = try? jsonArrayencoding.encode(urlRequest, with: nil)

        var request: Alamofire.DataRequest? = customAlamofireManager.request(jsonAryEncodedRequest!)
        request?.validate{request, response, data in
            return .success
            }
            .responseJSON {
...
}
```

}
Instead of using request(url,method, parameters,encoding, headers), make the encodedRequest manually first, then using it init alamofire's datarequest.